# Windows defender thread using 100% CPU

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, windows-defender, high-cpu-usage

The problem is the following - a thread of windows defender hangs and consumes 100% of one core (viewed with process explorer). It happens only when there is InPrivate IE instance running. The result is that IE becomes completely unresponsive and the solution is to just kill the offending thread (not process) from process explorer. Then it returns to normal.

If the thread is not killed it will stay in that situation indefinitely.

What could cause such behaviour (also happens when php running under apache 2.2 tries to make file_get_contents - but I am not completely sure about that)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue since the first MSE beta and MS ignores all feedback.

Here is what I see in Windows 8:

[image]

There is no way to fix it. Switch to a different AV tool.